# kevin's word list SCOWL contains unreadable/illegal words?

Tags: list, cpu-word

i found many unreadable words in kevin's word list (SCOWL), english-words.35 for example, at the end of the file, there are three words that are unreadable or messed up, all the three words start with '0xE9', which can not be interpreted as english letter.

i have no clue what these words should be and how to correct them, has anyone noticed this and would you please tell me the reason? thank you.

P.S. my OS is Windows 7

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your criteria for "unreadable" and "messed up" are but according to the [README](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/scowl-readme) file for [SCOWL](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/):

> Accents are present on certain words
>   such as café in [iso8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) format.

The three words you mention are éclair, éclair's and éclairs which are fine.

If you could post the part of your code that is giving you trouble perhaps somebody could help further. This is a programming issue right? :)

Comment: Thanks Arnold Spence for the clarification. the three words are fine now when i changed to iso8859-1 charset in Notepad++. <br> Thanks again and Stackoverflow Rocks~~